# How to use a [slideshow] image as a link

Tags: php, image, hyperlink, slideshow

I'm having an issue using images from a Slideshow as links.

This is my code:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default sl-2">
    <div id="slider-2" class="nivoSlider-2" >
    <?php foreach ($items as $key=>$item):  ?>
        <?php if($params->get('itemImage') && isset($item->image)): ?>

            <a class="moduleItemTitle" href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $path1;?>?src=<?php echo $item->image;?>&w=635&h=386&zc=1&q=100" alt="<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($item->title); ?>" title="#htmlcaption<?php echo $key;?>"/>
            </a>

        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <?php foreach ($items as $key=>$item):  ?>
    <div id="htmlcaption<?php echo $key;?>" class="nivo-html-caption">
    <?php if($params->get('itemTitle')): ?>
        <!--<h2><a class="moduleItemTitle" href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>"><?php echo $item->title; ?></a></h2>-->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="clr"></div>
        <?php if($params->get('itemIntroText')): ?>
        <div class="description-slider2">
            <p><?php echo $item->introtext; ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?> 
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

I pass through the "a" tag the $item->link parameter which returns these two strings since the slideshow only contains two images:

string(51) `/demo-catarroja2/es/campanas/cavi-catarroja-virtual`

&

string(49) `/demo-catarroja2/es/campanas/plan-de-ayuda-social`

If I inspect the element with a web browser it shows this:

```
<a class="moduleItemTitle" href="/demo-catarroja2/es/campanas/plan-de-ayuda-social">
    <img src="http://complusoft.net/demo-catarroja2/templates/onews/html/thumb.php?src=/demo-catarroja2/media/k2/items/cache/9c2fe6cb8c357cf6d57c8926869c1003_XL.jpg&w=635&h=386&zc=1&q=100" alt="Plan de Ayuda social 2013" title="#htmlcaption1"/>
</a>
```

This image is obviously inside the a tag but its acting as a link, why could this be?

You can check out the site here:  
The slideshow is on the main page up top.

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly?

Comment: I meant not acting as a link :P